# Instantiate an object for all the available functions

Tags: php

I have a lot of functions in my PHP file.

I need to instantiate this object `$twitterObj = new EpiTwitter(TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY, TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET);` and have it available for every function in the file and I do not want to repeat it on every function..

Is there a way to do it? To instantiate this object without having to copy and paste it to every single function I have on file?

Thanks

Comment: I know this is an old question, but you should consider accepting an answer.

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution is to use the [`global`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php#language.variables.scope.global) keyword.

```
$twitterObj = new EpiTwitter(TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY, TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET);

function myFunc()
{
    global $twitterObj;

    $twitterObj->doStuff();
}
```

A nicer option is injection.

```
function myFunc(EpiTwitter $twitterObj)
{
    $twitterObj->doStuff();
}
```

I would always go with injection.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `global`, you can wrap instantiation in a function.

```
function getTwitterObj()
{
   static $obj = null;
   if ($obj == null) {
      $obj = new EpiTwitter(TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY, TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET);
   }
   return $obj;
}
```

You can even do this in your functions:

```
  getTwitterObj()->doStuff();
```

Also, if you are using classes, you can take a look at Singleton pattern.

Comment: That is, in a lot of ways, just a glorified global, though it does address some of the concerns a global presents.  (As for a singleton, I lean even more towards that being a glorified global.)

Answer (score 0):

The generally considered 'best' way is to pass is as a parameter to each function:

```
function a(EpiTwitter $twitter) { }
function b(EpiTwitter $twitter) { }
```

The lazy way (and I advise against this unless it's a small script that's not likely to grow), is to just create it in the global scope and then use the global keyword to pull it into functions:

```
$twitter = ...;
function a() { 
    global $twitter;
    //$twitter is now the twitter from above.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An instance of an object is held in a variable, and is therefore subject to [the same scoping rules](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) of any other variable in PHP. There are a few ways to achieve what you want to do, but what you *cannot* do is make it available to every function "automatically" with no modification to the function.

You would need to instantiate your object in the global scope and "import" it into the scope of the function somehow. To do this, you have three options:

- The `$GLOBALS` array (documented in the link above)
- The `global` keyword (documented in the link above)
- Passing the object in as an [argument](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php)

Options 1 and 2 are mostly considered "bad practice" as they can make the program flow more confusing, they are not particularly scalable, and they do not promote the ability to re-use your code in other projects. The "best" way to do this is to pass the object in as an argument.

Option 1:

```
$twitterObj = new EpiTwitter(TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY, TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET);

function my_func () {
  $twitterObj = $GLOBALS['twitterOjb'];
  // do stuff
}
```

Option 2:

```
$twitterObj = new EpiTwitter(TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY, TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET);

function my_func () {
  global $twitterObj;
  // do stuff
}
```

Option 3:

```
$twitterObj = new EpiTwitter(TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY, TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET);

function my_func ($twitterObj) {
  // do stuff
}

my_func($twitterObj);
```

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

You can declare variables to be global inside functions:

```
function my_func () {
    global $myGlobalObject;
    // function code
}
```

Inside this function, variable `$myGlobalObject` is a variable from the global scope: It will persis after the function returns, available to other functions (if they declare a `global` variable of the same name) and all code outside a function.

This is actually a bad practice, and you should avoid it. Instead, define your functions to accept a parameter, which you will pass every time. You will only need to instantiate it once. An example:

```
function my_func_a ( $myObj ) {
    // function code
}

function my_func_b ( $myObj ) {
    // function code
}

// the actual script...
$twitterObj = new EpiTwitter( TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY, TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET );
my_func_a( $twitterObj );
my_func_b( $twitterObj );
// etc...
```

Only use global variables inside functions if you *really* need to. Always try to avoid it.